# Combining images in ASP.Net MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

We need to create a single jpg image from a range of existing jpgs. The user can select a range of parts in the front end of our application using JQuery. We then need to take all the parts and flatten them to create a single image.

All the parts will exist in an image directory. For example part 1 is the base image which all other parts are overlaid on. We then may choose part 8 - will will always appear at a certain point on top of the base image. We may then choose part 15 which will also appear at a certain point. Other than the base image no part can ever intersect with any other part.

Any advice on how to achieve this? Any good Nuget packages etc that could help

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all there for you in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

Start by creating a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) to draw into. Create a [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx) object from that Bitmap.
[Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx) each of your images. Then use [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage) to draw each one onto the target. Finish with the [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) method.